# Optimising Self join queries in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, left-join, oracle-sqldeveloper, self-join

I am trying to execute the below query and it takes more time to get executed. Could you please say how I can optimize this query to execute in faster manner.  Also please say how to understand the results of EXPLAIN PLAN?

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.*,
                T3.*
FROM   table1 T1
       join table1 T2
         ON T2.no = T1.no
       left outer join table2 T3
                    ON T1.record_id = T3.record_id
WHERE  T2.standard IN ( 'TE' )
       AND Upper(T2.ind) = 'PRI'
       AND ( ( T2.input = 'SIT'
               AND T2.batch_no IS NOT NULL )
              OR T2.input <> 'SIT' )
       AND Upper(T1.ind) IN ( 'PRI', 'CNJ' )
       AND T1.id_no = T2.id_no
ORDER  BY T1.no,
          T1.ind DESC
```

Comment: use `EXPLAIN PLAN` and  see the result and rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I got the result of EXPLAIN PLAN. Could you please say how to understand  the results?

Comment: Add it to your question.